# Adding groups in Spring security

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to use the group abstraction in my application. However I don't understand how to configure it nor which tables I need. Is it right that you have one user table with the username, password and enabled column in addition to other things such as first name? Then you need these tables: `groups`, `groups_authorities` and `group_members`?

Wouldn't it be bad to duplicate the username in both the user table and group_members table? I don't get how it relates to eachother. Some of what I have found...

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.java
?

```
create table groups (
  id bigint generated by default as identity(start with 0) primary key,
  group_name varchar_ignorecase(50) not null);

create table group_authorities (
  group_id bigint not null,
  authority varchar(50) not null,
  constraint fk_group_authorities_group foreign key(group_id) references groups(id));

create table group_members (
  id bigint generated by default as identity(start with 0) primary key,
  username varchar(50) not null,
  group_id bigint not null,
  constraint fk_group_members_group foreign key(group_id) references groups(id));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: I am not sure that I understand completely your question. For now I think the response will be yes.

Q2: yes.

Q3: it depends. If you have / may have in the future a "change username" feature then it's bad. Good news is that you can customize DB schema. For example add an id field to users table and use this field as PK (make sure that username field is unique in this case). Now you must ovverride default SQL queries from `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl`:

```
public static final String DEF_USERS_BY_USERNAME_QUERY =
        "select username,password,enabled " +
        "from users " +
        "where username = ?";
public static final String DEF_AUTHORITIES_BY_USERNAME_QUERY =
        "select username,authority " +
        "from authorities " +
        "where username = ?";
public static final String DEF_GROUP_AUTHORITIES_BY_USERNAME_QUERY =
        "select g.id, g.group_name, ga.authority " +
        "from groups g, group_members gm, group_authorities ga " +
        "where gm.username = ? " +
        "and g.id = ga.group_id " +
        "and g.id = gm.group_id";
```

You can do it in your security config:

```xml
  <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
      <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="securityDataSource" 
          users-by-username-query="your customized SQL goes here"
          authorities-by-username-query="your customized SQL goes here"
          group-authorities-by-username-query="your customized SQL goes here"
      />
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need a own group_members table when you have this info in a users table. Could you explain?

Comment: Which info? Just username field? It is here to make a reference between two tables (users and group_members). Explanation: imagine that you have 3 users username={user1, user2, user3}. And you want give them 2 roles, ROLE_A and ROLE_B. In this case you can add new group (one record in **groups** table). Then add 3 users to this group (3 new records in **group_members**  table). Then affect to this group two roles (two new records in **group_authorities** table). Is it clear for you?

Comment: Not really. I mean you have a users table right? It contains username, password, enabled, firstname, lastname, age etc. Why do you need a second table named group_members (I know you can change this name) that only contains a username? Why not have just users, groups and group_authorities? Why the group_members table.

Comment: Using this table you can add users from `users` table into some group from `groups` table. In other words each time when you put a user into some group you will add a record in **group_authorities** table.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: OK, I was concentrated on technical reason. It looks like you want functional reason. And it is simple: you can put one user into multiple different groups in the same time. On a DB level it means many to many relationship between two entities => additional table (**group_members**). Remove this table, and a group_id field in users table, and a user will be able to participate in only one group in the same moment. Is it answer the question for you?

Comment: Yes, that answers my question. Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind why I need to add the query for `authorities-by-username-query` when I use groups? And do I specify the group name in the access attribute of the intercept-url element instead of a role?

Comment: Normally groups are an addition to standard authorities. By default JdbcDaoImpl requires authorities table AFAIK. You can skip this table. But in this case you must provide some fake `authorities-by-username-query` for JdbcDaoImpl or replace JdbcDaoImpl by your custom implementation. I have no tried group name in intercept-url, so can't say.

Comment: Alright, so when you put a user in a group you just "automatically" assigns a bunch of authorties, but you still use the autorities in the access attribute? You can't say: This should be allowed for all users belonging to Moderator group for instance?